# Javascript conditionally call chained method

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is there a chance to conditionally run a chained method ?

I want to simplify this expression to be a one-liner but can't find a solution for the blocking `.not.` on the expect.

```js
const checkSomething = (element, value = true) => {
  if (value) {
    expect(element).toBeVisible()
  } else {
    expect(element).not.toBeVisible()
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not simpler, but it is one line. not 100% positive this works but seems like it should. fwiw i think your code is fine and would keep it that way. very readable. `(value ? expect(element): expect(element).not).toBeVisible()`

Comment: @CollinD thanks for the help, however I was looking to know if there was a way with optional chaining to call this conditionally. [mozilla docs ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: No, that's not really what optional chaining is for. And you're not calling `.not`, `expect(...).not` is just another object with the same structure as `expect(...)` returns, but all of the expects run off of it will be reversed. So you're just conditionally selecting one of two objects to call a method on. Optional chaining is for optionally accessing a member iff the object is not nullish. Doesn't seem applicable here. Note that `?.` is a binary operator, and you want to essentially use 3 different parameters (object, member, condition), but `condition` is always `object != null` w/ `?.`

Comment: Just does not define a `toBeVisible` method - what plugins are you using? If you're open to more, there might be some that provide "filler" words, so you can write `expect(element)[value ? 'be' : 'not'].toBeVisible()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an immediately invoked arrow function to create a one-liner expression:

```
const checkSomething = (element, value = true) => {
  (e => value ? e : e.not)(expect(element)).toBeVisible()
}
```

This is basically the same as

```
const checkSomething = (element, value = true) => {
  const e = expect(element);
  (value ? e : e.not).toBeVisible()
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the first one, but looking at it and I find it pretty difficult to read, I would go with the second option

Comment: You asked for a one-liner expression, not for something that is easy to read :-) I wouldn't recommend the first option either.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an optional chaining, but if you define your construct as

```
const expectMaybe = (arg, val) => val ? expect(arg) : expect(arg).not;
```

then maybe you can write your oneliner as

```
const checkSomething = (element, value=true) => expectMaybe(element, value).toBeVisible();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator.

```
const checkSomething = (element, value = true) => value ? expect(element).toBeVisible() : expect(element).not.toBeVisible()
```

Comment: I know how to use a ternary, was asking if there was a way to conditionally call the `.not`. I also don't want to return anything

Comment: @nabais No there is not a way to conditionally "call" `.not` (that's not a function, that's an object) other than this or the if statement or its variations, and for if whatever reason you don't want to return anything, just wrap the body in `{` and `}`